# How can I control which data gets reported to the Istio Mixer by the side car?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-health-check, envoyproxy

How can I control the data being sent to the Istio Mixer? For example, my service has a health url (/health) that gets called every few seconds and the call goes through the side car which end up reporting data to the mixer. How can I configure the side car to skip metrics/reports related to certain URLs like the health url?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might still be in [development](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.policy.v1beta1/#Uri). If/when it works, I believe you could use the [themonitoredResourceDimensions](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/metric/#Template) with an [expression](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/expression-language/) for [uriValue](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.policy.v1beta1/#Uri).